# HTML Div has no method appendTo()

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm getting this error in the console:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'appendTo'`
JS File

```
$('#refresh-button').click(function()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error make sense. HTML [`Element`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element) indeed do not have an `appendTo` method.

You can convert your HTML Div element to a jQuery object by passing it to jQuery

```
var jqObject = $(myDivElement); // now I can call appendTo on jqObject
jqObject.appendTo(parent);
```

Alternatively, you can use the native DOM method:

```
// this also works, assuming theParent is a DOM element too
theParent.appendChild(myDivElement); 
// of if it's a jQuery object
theParent.append(myDivelement);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure where those variables are coming from, but the problem is that they are pointing to native DOM elements, not to jQuery selections. `appendTo` is a jQuery function, not a DOM function.

The easy solution is to use the jQuery selection you're already creating:

```
product_title.appendTo($("#product_name"));
// becomes
$("#product_name").append(product_title);
```

and likewise for the other variables.

The other way is to turn the native element into a jQuery selection with the `$()` wrapper, but that would be less efficient, as you'd have to create two selections:

```
$(product_title).appendTo($("#product_name"));
```

Comment: @user3120646 Oh, those variables work fine! You can tell that by the error message you're getting. You'd get a "Cannot call method `'appendTo'` of `undefined`" error if it wasn't. I'm merely saying that I don't fully understand your code!

Comment: @user3120646 I genuinely don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing a point... but I don't see where these variables are set

```
    product_title
    product_shape
    product_size
    product_metal
    product_stock
    product_price
```

Comment: They're set here: `<div class='product' id="product_title"></div>` due to a little known *feature*

Comment: Well, then probably solution to your problem's in @lonesomeday answer

Comment: I kinda hate this *"feature"* due to how it interacts with methods such as form.submit()

Comment: @KevinB today I learned. (Worth mentioning that aside from being generally horrible - in some browsers in standards mode this apparently does not work)